# PWM for 48V Brushless DC motor control

Tags: pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, speed

I am converting a lawn mower to electric motor driven. I have a 1800W 48V 26A brushless motor. Rated speed is 3000 rpm. I need to run it at 1800rpm for direct drive. From other conversions I have seen, my motor should have more than adequate torque at the reduced speed. I have several 18V batteries which I can obviously configure for 36V, 54V etc.
I am trying to select a PWM controller. A typical one is described as 48V 72V 3000W. Used foe ATVs etc. I am hoping to try 36V initially and adjust to get 1800rpm. Will this work? One issue is that many of the controllers have a low voltage cut out. How do I work around this? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: For a brushless motor you need a brushless controller, a PWM controller would be suitable for PMDC brushed motors.